# jQuery AnythingSlider - change properties after initial setup

Tags: javascript, jquery, anythingslider

If you have Anything slider setup on a page like something like so

```
$('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider({
  easing: "easeInOutExpo",
  autoPlay: true,
  delay: 5000,
  startStopped: false,
  animationTime: 600,
  hashTags: true,
  buildNavigation: true,
  pauseOnHover: true,
  navigationFormatter: formatText
});
```

How can you later change an individual property - say `delay=10000`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the API to access the options. In the newest version `.anythingSlider` isn't the element to initialize AnythingSlider on, it ends up being named as `.anythingBase`.

```
$('#slider').data('AnythingSlider').options.delay = 10000;
```

I'll update the [usage wiki page](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki/Usage) to show this more explicitly.